# ruby callback when state changes

Tags: ruby, clojure

Is there a way to provide similar functionality in ruby to what [add-watch](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/add-watch) does in clojure? I am looking for a way to register a block/proc/lambda as a callback on a data structure, say a hash, and be called whenever the state of the hash changes.

Comment: yes, there is a way to provide such functionality as evident in Activerecord::Observer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in Ruby, but you'll need to build up the infrastructure yourself or find a library that does it.

Because of [Ruby's "duck" typing](http://rubysource.com/making-ruby-quack%E2%80%94why-we-love-duck-typing/), a method that expects a Hash instance can be given a class instance that looks, feels, and sounds like a hash. The receiving method can just treat the object as a hash and everything will be fine.

**Meanwhile**, your other software will know that it is really an `ObservableHash` (or whatever you decide to call it.) And you will have registered your callback-on-change methods, etc.

Here's a [blog post](http://pullmonkey.com/2008/01/06/convert-a-ruby-hash-into-a-class-object/) that will help get you started on creating your `ObservableHash`.

A final tip: be sure to implement *all* of the Hash methods. That way the other methods that receive it won't be able to tell the difference between an observable_hash and a hash.

It is my understanding that the Rails `ActionController#params` "hash" is, in fact, a class instance that seems to be a hash (but really isn't). Look up its source to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some examples of aspect oriented programming if that is what you are after:

- [aquarium](http://aquarium.rubyforge.org/)
- [aspector](https://github.com/gcao/aspector)